# How do I convert this SQL query into Active Record statements?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here's the query:

```
select dogs.winning_status from dogs join cats on dogs.cat_id = cat.id where cats.cat_type = 'big' and dogs.user_id = 29 order by dogs.created_at DESC limit 2;
```

I have no idea how to convert this into an active record query though. I've looked at numerous rails sites (including [this one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)) I have no idea how to approach this at all though. I've tried a few different attempts, and all have failed.

Comment: I understand that. But I have no clue on how to conver this to active record. I've looked at numerous rails sites (including this one: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

I have no idea how to approach this at all though. I've tried a few different attempts, and all have failed.

This site is to ask technical questions. THat's all I'm doing. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you've got everything set up according to Rails's conventions.

```
Dog.joins(:cats).select(:winning_status).where("cats.cat_type = 'big' AND dogs.user_id = 29").order(:created_at).limit(2)
```

or this one

```
Dog.joins(:cats).select(:winning_status).where("cats.cat_type = ?", 'big').where(user_id: 29).order(:created_at).limit(2)
```

Comment: awesome, thanks so much! I kept messing up where to put the "where" clause, so I was getting an error or I was getting wrong results. thanks for your help!